# Split while preserving quotes in C using GLib

Tags: python, c, glib

I have a GLib String in as follows:

> Hello World! My name is "John Smith"

I'd like to split it to that the following tokens are what I'd get:

> Hello
> World!
> My
> name
> is
> "John Smith"

I would like to preserve quotes if possible. The closest analogy I can draw to this is Python's shlex.split():

```py
import shlex

shlex.split(s, posix=False)
```

I've tried g_strsplit but it doesn't preserve quotes as I'd like it to.

Comment: Ah-ha! https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.shell_parse_argv.html

Comment: The function will probably treat single quotes too.  It might remove the quotes too — it is meant to emulate a shell parsing a string and a shell removes the quotes.

Comment: I've used that function now but I can't figure out how to print the values within the `gchar***`

Comment: It's not *really* a `char ***`, it's just a `char **` and the extra `*` is there because it's an output parameter. You'd use it something like: `gint argc; gchar **argv; g_shell_parse_argv(line, &argc, &argv, NULL); for (gint i = 0; i < argc; i++) puts(argv[i]); g_strfreev(argv);